# Array to setup Checkboxes and save results to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, winforms, checkbox

I am following on from my previous question as I never got a full response. [Reference previous object created in loop to update SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760263/reference-previous-object-created-in-loop-to-update-sql)

Basically, I have changed my syntax to the following, however there are two problems with it:

1. The Checkboxes don't actually appear.
2. In the saveOrderBtn_Click loop, I get the error message "The name 'myBoxes' does not exist in the current context". This is on the "if" statement line.

I cannot use Controls.Add(myCheckBox); as when you do the update, this updates everything in SQL based upon the last checkbox created in the loop - it does not count each checkbox.

I am still learning C#. Thank you very much in advanced.

UPDATED CODE:

```
public partial class SelectUsers : Form { 

// DECLARE THE myCheckBox
private CheckBox myCheckBox;

public SelectUsers()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void SelectUsers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = myconnection.runSelect(new DataSet(), "THE SELECT");

    int xAxisCheckbox = 40;
    int yAxisCheckbox = 50;

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        // CHANGED List<CheckBox> myBoxes LINE
        List<CheckBox> myBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();

        myCheckBox = new CheckBox();
        myCheckBox.Location = new Point(xAxisCheckbox, yAxisCheckbox);
        myCheckBox.Size = new Size(120, 20);
        myCheckBox.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FullName"].ToString();
        myCheckBox.Checked = (bool)ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["InOperation"];
        yAxisCheckbox = yAxisCheckbox + 80;

        // THIS SHOULD ADD/RENDER EACH CHECKBOX, BUT IT DOESN'T
        myBoxes.Add(myCheckBox);
    }
}

private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = myconnection.runSelect(new DataSet(), "THE SELECT");

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        userID = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserID"];
        if (myBoxes[i].Checked)
        {
            myconnection.runUpdate("UPDATE Users SET InOperation = 1, OperationOrder = CASE WHEN OperationOrder = 1 THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN InOperation=1 THEN OperationOrder ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM Users WHERE InOperation=1 AND OperationOrder > 0) END END WHERE UserID=" + userID);
            myconnection.runUpdate("UPDATE Users SET OperationOrder = CASE WHEN OperationOrder = 0 THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE InOperation=1) ELSE OperationOrder END WHERE InOperation=1");
        }
        else
        {
            myconnection.runUpdate("UPDATE Users SET InOperation = 0, OperationOrder = 0 WHERE UserID=" + userID);
            myconnection.runUpdate("UPDATE Users SET OperationOrder = CASE WHEN OperationOrder -1 = 0 THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE InOperation=1) ELSE OperationOrder -1 END WHERE InOperation=1");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your declaration of myBoxes outside the loop will make it so you have the exact same checkbox in all positions of myBoxes (as you keep redefining the same checkbox). Where is the code that uses myBoxes to render items to the page? Your save also depends on the database not changing in between the load and the save.

Comment: @EricH Thanks for the reply. So is the updated code example ok for declaring myBoxes (see above)? The code I have posted is everything to get the checkboxes working, although it clearly isn't working, so I guess I need more code to render the checkboxes other than just "myBoxes.Add(myCheckBox);"? Please could I have an example to get them displaying? And the database is unlikely to change between the load and save button click. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading programming books, I discovered that you do not create an array like this, it is done in the following way:

```
// Global
CheckBox[] myCheckBox;
DataSet ds;

private void SelectUsers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    ds = myconnection.runSelect(new DataSet(), "THE SELECT");

    int xAxisCheckbox = 40;
    int yAxisCheckbox = 50;

    // Create the CheckBox array (amount based on number of rows)
    myBoxes = new CheckBox[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        // Create a new Checkbox
        myCheckBox[i] = new CheckBox();

        myCheckBox.Location = new Point(xAxisCheckbox, yAxisCheckbox);
        myCheckBox.Size = new Size(120, 20);
        myCheckBox.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FullName"].ToString();
        myCheckBox.Checked = (bool)ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["InOperation"];
        yAxisCheckbox = yAxisCheckbox + 80;

        // Add the Checkbox
        Controls.Add(myCheckBox[i]);
    }
}

private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        userID = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserID"];

        if (myBoxes[i].Checked)
        {
            myconnection.runUpdate("UPDATE Users SET InOperation = 1, OperationOrder = CASE WHEN OperationOrder = 1 THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN InOperation=1 THEN OperationOrder ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM Users WHERE InOperation=1 AND OperationOrder > 0) END END WHERE UserID=" + userID);
            myconnection.runUpdate("UPDATE Users SET OperationOrder = CASE WHEN OperationOrder = 0 THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE InOperation=1) ELSE OperationOrder END WHERE InOperation=1");
        }
        else
        {
            myconnection.runUpdate("UPDATE Users SET InOperation = 0, OperationOrder = 0 WHERE UserID=" + userID);
            myconnection.runUpdate("UPDATE Users SET OperationOrder = CASE WHEN OperationOrder -1 = 0 THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE InOperation=1) ELSE OperationOrder -1 END WHERE InOperation=1");
        }
    }
}
```